# Unable to open Telegram

Tags: 20.04

```
(process:19783): Telegram-WARNING **: 13:21:32.689: Unfortunately, GTK integration conflicts with qgtk2 platformtheme and style. Therefore, QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME and QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE will be unset.
Telegram-Message: 13:21:32.689: This can be ignored by setting TDESKTOP_I_KNOW_ABOUT_GTK_INCOMPATIBILITY environment variable to any value, however, if qgtk2 theme or style is used, this will lead to a crash.
Telegram-Message: 13:21:32.689: GTK integration can be disabled by setting TDESKTOP_DISABLE_GTK_INTEGRATION to any value. Keep in mind that this will lead to clipboard issues and tdesktop will be unable to get settings from GTK (such as decoration layout, dark mode & more).
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
```

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem :

```
Telegram-WARNING **: 11:54:14.523: Unfortunately, GTK integration conflicts with qgtk2 platformtheme and style. Therefore, QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME and QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE will be unset.
Telegram-Message: 11:54:14.528: This can be ignored by setting TDESKTOP_I_KNOW_ABOUT_GTK_INCOMPATIBILITY environment variable to any value, however, if qgtk2 theme or style is used, this will lead to a crash.
Telegram-Message: 11:54:14.528: GTK integration can be disabled by setting TDESKTOP_DISABLE_GTK_INTEGRATION to any value. Keep in mind that this will lead to clipboard issues and tdesktop will be unable to get settings from GTK (such as decoration layout, dark mode & more).
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
```

for me it's fixed by refreshing telegram :

```
sudo snap refresh telegram-desktop
```

Comment: Thanks Dude!! for response and it worked